# Strange behavior to searchable JQuery Connected Sortable. Need fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using a connected sortable that saves wonderfully via asp.net back-end on a button click. Additional features include the ability to search each of the lists. This works well until you do the drop and drag of an item from one list to another. When I do the search of the one list using JavaScript to search items in the one list, it still thinks that it is a part of the first list. Has anyone seen this behavior? and do you know of a possible fix to make item permanently part of the said dragged upon list within the DOM. This behavior is in FF, IE, Chrome, etc.

Now I do have buttons on this list that move items from one list to the other based on them being selected then button clicked, it is then a part of the second list using JQuery append();. This makes the item a permanent part of the second list's DOM and is able to be searched upon within that list.

Comment: You should add some code examples to help clarify your question.

Comment: JW. I started recreating the issue in JS fiddle to show my issue...Then I found my solution. I was recalling a unique class to each list in the search JS function I created. Now to create a function to switch the name of the classes when dragged to each column

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it resolved!  I would still suggest, however, that you post some code related to your precise issue and then answer your question with the way you got it working.  That way, future stackers that might have your same problem will be able to benefit from your hard work!

Comment: Thanks JW but due to the discussion I am recreating it in JSFiddle and when I have ironed out the bugs I will post it under here to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my "Ah-Ha" moment. It was doing what it was supposed to do looking for the item and showing it and if it was not the item it wouldn't show it. however when the item moved to the other column using sortable it still had the same class as the first column. I needed to make that switch.

The answer is here as follows...
http://jsfiddle.net/6jmLvysj/

```
         $(input)
         .change(function () {
         var filter = $(this).val();
         if (filter) {
             //here is my DAH moment it is looking for this class so when the user was typing in the first search input it was looking for item it would be searching for it is the second column--give myself a Gib slap--
             $(list).find(".ui-state-default:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").hide();
             $(list).find("ui-state-default:Contains(" + filter + ")").show();
         } else {
             $(list).find(".ui-state-default").show();
         }
         return false;
     })
         .keyup(function () {

         $(this).change();
     });
```

then this

```
     //so here is where I changed this code when the user brings the item over then it changes it to the proper respected class depending where the user drops it so it can be searched. 
     stop: function (event, ui) {
         if (ui.item.hasClass("ui-state-default")) {
             ui.item.attr('class', 'ui-state-highlight');
         }
         else {
             ui.item.attr('class', 'ui-state-default');
         }
```